# Can we use 'rather than' and 'or at least' together?

Tags: grammar

Can we use 'rather than' and 'or at least' together?

> Paying attention on arts rather than, or at least, as equal as health and defence services could pave the way for founding morally well established societies and raising people with good humour.

Comment: I can't make any sense of that sentence.

Comment: As WeatherVane says, your sentence is a bit difficult to understand. It might help if you explain what it is supposed to mean by breaking it down into shorter sentences- one or two clauses per sentence.

Comment: It's _equal to_, not _as equal as_ - but the phrases you have used don't make sense together.

Comment: Is it intended to mean this paraphrasing? *Funding the arts to the same extent as health and defence services could lead to a happier and more moral society.*

Comment: I want to combine these two sentences; "Paying attention on arts rather than health and defence services could pave the way for..."  and "paying attention arts as equal as to health and defence services could pave the way for..." thank you all for your help by the way

Comment: Paying *at least as much* attention to the arts as to health and ...

Comment: Thank you so much..

Comment: @WeatherVane: Or *Paying **as much or more** attention to the arts as to health and...* But yours is more common *and* it was posted first, so I think the onus is on *you* to convert your comment into an answer here! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am unsure I can support an answer with references, and the entire sentence needs to be revised anyway, but proof-reading is off-topic so I will make the choice you frequently make to comment rather than answer, but I don't mind if you can fashion an answer yourself.